# perl get reference to temp list returned by function without making a copy?

Tags: perl

I have a function in perl that returns a list. It is my understanding that when foo() is assigned to list a copy is made:

```
sub foo() { return `ping 127.0.0.1` }

my @list = foo();
```

That `@list` then needs to be transferred to another list like `@oldlist = @list;` and another copy is made. So I was thinking can I just make a reference from the returned list like `my $listref = \foo();` and then I can assign that reference, but that doesn't work.

The function I'm working with runs a command that returns a pretty big list (the ping command is just for example purposes) and I have call it often so I want to minimize the copies if possible. what is a good way to deal with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make an anonymous array reference of the list that is returned

```
my $listref = [ foo() ];
```

But, can you not return an arrayref to start with?  That is better in general, too.

---

What you attempted "takes a reference of a list" ... what one cannot do in the literal sense; a list stands for a mere collection of scalars in a program<sup>†</sup>, while a [reference can be taken](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) (my emphasis)

> By using the backslash operator on a **variable**, **subroutine**, or **value**.

and a "list" isn't either (with a subroutine we need syntax `\&sub_name`)

However, with the `\` operator a reference *is* taken, either to each element of the list if in list context

```
my @ref_of_LIST = \( 1,2,3 );  #-->  @ref_of_LIST: (\1, \2, \3)
```

or to a scalar if in scalar context, which is what happens in your attempt. Since your sub returns a list of values, they are evaluated by the [comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) and discarded, one by one, until the last one.  The reference is then taken of that scalar

```
my $ref_of_LIST = \( 1,2,3 );  #--> $ref_of_LIST: \3
```

As it happens, all this applies without parens as well, with `\foo()`.

---

<sup>†</sup> See the last part of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018151/4653379) (and links in it), for example

Comment: I don't know how to return an array ref from a command that returns a list. Would it be acceptable to do it as `return [\`ping 1.2.3.4\`];`

Comment: @newguy Yes, that would be a fine way to do it.  Another is to store the command's return in an array variable (say, `@ary`) -- if you need it elsewhere in the sub -- and then `return \@ary;`

Comment: Ok thanks. Wouldn't the @ary way create a copy though

Comment: @newguy For one, those elements must be stored somewhere, either anonymously by `[ .. ]` or associated with a named variable by `@ary = .. `.  I don't know whether yet an extra copy is made in order to construct an array, but I'd expect that it isn't When you `return \@ary` no new copies are made.  I would expect that they are about the same.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can benchmark them.  Write two subs that return a (large!) array in these two ways, and time them using [Benchmark](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html). It's _very_ simple to use. If there is an extra copy made you'll know that. Like with all benchmarks, watch out so you compare apples to apples :)

Comment: @newguy  I added an explanation of what happens with `\foo()`