# perl GetOptions, option-triggered subroutine that accepts arguments

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine

I am trying to use the `GetOptions` function from `GetOpt::Long` to call a subroutine that accepts an argument. However, the subroutine gets called regardless of whether the option is specified on the command line. This unexpected behavior does not occur if an argument is not passed to the subroutine in the `GetOptions` line.

What follows is a minimal demonstration of the problem:

If an argument is provided to the subroutine in the `GetOptions` line, the subroutine ends up being called regardless of whether its controlling option is supplied on the command line:

```
$ cat a1.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
my $var="entered";
GetOptions ( "opt" => \&sub1($var) );
sub sub1 { print "sub1 $_[0]\n"; }

$ perl a1.pl --opt
sub1 entered

$ perl a1.pl
sub1 entered
```

In contrast, if the subroutine is called in `GetOptions` without an argument, it behaves appropriately:

```
$ cat a2.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
GetOptions ( "opt" => \&sub2 );
sub sub2 { print "sub2 entered\n"; }

$ perl a2.pl --opt
sub2 entered

$ perl a2.pl
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I know that I can simply set a variable that controls whether the subroutine is called after the `GetOptions` block, but I would like to determine the correct syntax for calling the subroutine within the `GetOptions` line, as well as understand why the observed behavior is happening.

Comment: Wow, the second question I've seen today that actually contains a [mcve].  I _rarely_ see two such questions in one day.  Congratulations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [expects a *code reference*](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options), and that is taken with the sub name alone (`\&name`) or as an anonymous sub; there is no notion of "arguments" as you are not making a function call but rather obtaining a reference (to code). Then call you sub in that code.  Details follow.

Associate the option with an anonymous subroutine, inside of which you can call your sub

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;

my $opt;
my $var = 'entered';

GetOptions ( 'opt' => sub { $opt = 1; sub1($var) } );

sub sub1 { say "sub1 $_[0]"; }
```

Or use `'opt' => \&cb` and in the sub `cb()` call `sub1(...)`. This callback is passed the option name and value (or name, key, and value in case of a hash), and doesn't take other arguments. So you cannot in any way dynamically resolve what arguments to pass to `sub1()`.

The invocation in the question is not how a [subroutine reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) is obtained; you must only use the subroutine name, `\&name`. This is not about `Getopt`, which just wants a code reference.

When you attempt to "pass arguments" that isn't a coderef anymore but the sub is executed and then the reference taken of its return; same as `\sub()` or `\( sub() )`. This can be seen by

```
perl -wE'sub tt { say "@_"; return "ret" }; $r = \&tt("hi"); say $$r'
```

what prints

```
hi
ret
```

While this just isn't a way to take a reference let me still warn of possible [surprises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47258929/4653379) (if one ends up trying to take a "reference to a list")

Comment: What's up with TWO downvotes ?? If I'm going mad and blind would someone please let me know ?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since I did much Perl, but I'm pretty sure it is because

```
\&sub1($var)
```

is a reference to the *result* of invoking `sub1`.  That is, the line

```
GetOptions ( "opt" => \&sub1($var) );
```

actually invokes `sub($var)` as part of constructing the argument list to `GetOptions`.  This looks like a corner case in the syntax, you are taking a reference to the result of that invocation.

This should clear things up:

```
$ perl -de0

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49_001
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   0
  DB<1> sub sub1 { print "sub1\n"; }

  DB<2> sub1()
sub1

  DB<3> &sub1
sub1

  DB<4> \&sub1

  DB<5> x \&sub1
0  CODE(0x804d7fe8)
   -> &main::sub1 in (eval 6)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.22/perl5db.pl:737]:2-2
  DB<6> x \&sub1()
sub1
0  SCALAR(0x804ee7f0)
   -> 1
```